# Query on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT throwing dml_stats error

Tags: google-bigquery

I have recently started seeing an error when i simply run
`SELECT * FROM  region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT`

**Field name dml_stats does not exist in STRUCT<...**

Excluding field dml_stats doesn't seem to work either.

Anyone else spotted this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There are already 2 issues reported in the public issue tracker.

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193159258
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193437397

This seems to be a bug on the Google side. Hopefully, they will fix it soon.